# Check if class attribute was defined or derived in given class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

Example

```
class A:
    foo = 1

class B:
    foo = 2

class C:
    foo = 3

class D(A, B, C):
    pass

def collect_foo(cls):
    import inspect
    foos = []
    for c in inspect.getmro(cls):
        if hasattr(c, 'foo'):
            foos.append(c.foo)
    return foos
```

Now `collect_foo(D)` returns `[1, 1, 2, 3]` - `1` is doubled as `D` derives it from `A`. The question is - how to get unique `foo`s. First thing which came to my mind was checking if property is derived or declared in given class - is it possible? How to do that?

Comment: This is a nasty thing to do. Why are you doing it?

Comment: Also, does `set(collect_foo(D))` do what you want?

Comment: I'm gonna need to write about a hundred of classes, from which many will have specific compositions of features like `Class1(Feature1, Feature2)` or `Class2(Feature2, Feature1337)`. The thing is there are some attributes which I don't want to be overriden but mixed in and available for derived class - so one of the `Feature` classes provides the method to collect them all from inheritance hierarchy.
It's not that bad - if something is implementation-independent, version-independent (even 2.x/3.x) and well documented I wouldn't call it nasty hack.

Comment: if you have an attribute which you don't want to override, why would you define an attribute of a subclass with the same name? (Note that you can always get attributes of the base class using `super` anyway.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this will work... Look to see if it is in the `__dict__` attribute of the class.  But, be sure you really want to do this first.

Example:

```
if name in cls.__dict__:
    # ... your code here ...
    pass
```

Comment: Not exactly, but pretty close to Sven's answer which is what I've been looking for.

Comment: @Mikoskay: I actually don't see any significant difference to my answer.

Answer (score 17):

Just check

```
'foo' in c.__dict__
```

instead of

```
hasattr(c, 'foo')
```

This will only yield `True` if the attribute is defined in `c` itself.

Comment: Note that if the class has __slots__ instead, this will fail, so check both.

Answer (score 1):

"The thing is there are some attributes which I don't want to be overriden but mixed in and available for derived class"

This is exactly what the namespace mangling in Python does. The attributes that should not be overridden like this should start with two underscores. That way they don't get overridden, but remain unique for each class.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the accepted answer, but a `@classmethod` did not match my case...

I found it useful to check the class **dict** from the context of a base class or mix-in, where I only want to execute some code path if it applies to the derived class, such as if a particular method is overridden.

i.e. (in Python 3.6):
`if method_name in self.__class__.__dict__.keys():
    # do something`

I rationalized it as follows.

1. `self` is the instance
2. `__class__` is that instance's actual type
3. therefore, **dict** only contains the methods actually overridden in the derived class.